# Bootstrap collapse not working correctly after custom header height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn bootstrap by myself, but can't find the tutorials I need.

So, I'm posting my questions here. Hope you can help me.

This is what's happening:

- I used CSS to customise the nav height, because the default size wasn't right for this case.
- Unfortunately after I did that , on smaller screens the collapse doesn't behave properly.

Normal Size: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gjd87ndkigx49zm/Screenshot%202014-09-26%2013.53.27.png?dl=0
[image: Normal size]

Smaller Screens: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mxpufdig0beg5n/Screenshot%202014-09-26%2013.53.40.png?dl=0
[image: smaller screens]

What should I do?

I'll payback once I'm a pro at Bootstrap by helping other people on this community ahah

My warmest regards,

Ed

Comment: There are lot of tutorials on Bootstrap which can help you on this.. Here's the one.. http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/ :) and for your information you have to post your html and css here which makes others understand what changes you have done..

Comment: Give your css code please and html

Comment: The height of the .navbar is determined by the padding on the links, if you set the height of the navbar outside the min-width media query it will mess up the small viewport display. So put the height in a min-width media query where your menu breakpoint starts (usually 768px)

Comment: Thank you so much Christina , that was spot on!